# Making my Turtlebot with ASUS Xtion

Tags: xtion, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have read [tutorials](http://profmason.com/?p=1590) etc for making your own turtle bot, I wish to do it using [ASUS Xtion](http://answers.ros.org/question/12900/microsoft-kinect-or-asus-xtion); do I need to use the [modification kit](http://store.iheartengineering.com/TurtleBot-Kit-Kinect-Modification/dp/B0056QJC4I) as it is used when assembling the turtlebot using Microsoft Kinect ?

Any first hand experience will be most useful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29051/making-my-turtlebot-with-asus-xtion/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-03-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No; the Asus Xtion only needs USB power, and already has a USB connector.

If you want a bracket, iHeartEngineering makes one that is pretty nice: http://store.iheartengineering.com/I-Heart-Engineering-TurtleBot-Mounting/dp/B0073NXVW6

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-03-04**:
@ahendrix : Very nice ! makes sense to buy Xtion than Kinect !

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-03-04**:
You'll also need to launch the asus version of the TurtleBot urdf, if you want the camera to be correct in the visualization

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-03-04**:
@mwise_wg Thank you ! That never crossed my mind !

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-03-10**:
If you need it, the alternate URDF is available here. https://github.com/IHeartRobotics/iheart-ros-pkg/tree/master/ihe_hardware/turtlebot_xtion_top_description

Also, since it is open source the files for making your own are available here.
http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:16761

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-03-10**:
@I Heart Robotics Cheerio !

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2013-02-05**:
Your link is broken.